# Matching input string to similar dictionary keys Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary, pattern-matching, match

I have a dictionary `output_dict` that contains data pertaining to file signatures and their relevant extensions i.e. `'43 44 30 30 31': '.ISO'`. I am trying to write a script that will read a file in bytes and return any matches in the dictionary. If no match is found, return the most similar value.

Is there a way for it to read in a file byte by byte, matching as it goes until it reaches a byte that breaks the match, returning the previously matched key/value?

Alternatively, I would like it to be able to match a definite amount, or match something very similar (2-3 bytes difference). If no match or no similar object, I would want it to print a message.

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
root_path = "testdir"
list_of_files = os.listdir(root_path)
for files in list_of_files:
    full_path = os.path.join(root_path, files)
    open_it = open(full_path, 'rb')
    read_it = open_it.read(x)
    convert_it = get_bytes_as_displayable_hex(read_it)
    convert_to_ascii = convert_it.encode('utf-8')
    convert_to_string = convert_to_ascii.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors="strict")
    result = (output_dict.get(convert_to_string))
    if result is not None:
        print("Scan complete, found: {} file(s)".format(result))
    else:
        result = difflib.get_close_matches(convert_to_string, output_dict, 2, 0.2)
        print(result)
```

So, expected outcome would be something like a file's first 4 bytes are 25 50 44 46. These bytes are cross referenced with teh dictionary and will match it, returning ".PDF" as a result.

If the first four bytes are 25 50 44 47, this is not in the dictionary, but the code will still return ".PDF" as a result because they are very similar.

Any help is appreciated, as well as any advice, as I'm very very new to Python and programming in general.

Comment: "the most similar value" <- definition?

Comment: where the "most similar value" is a key that only differs by 2-3 hex bytes.
i.e. if FF D8 EE 00 is not a match, return FF D9 EE 00 as possible result.

Comment: Not very clear what is being asked for.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it much clearer. I will edit the post to add some more info to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found this interesting, so made a code snippet that might be useful for you. Assuming that every byte is allowed to have a small difference. Like in your comment that `FF D9 EE 00` would be acceptable if the control value was `FF D8 EE 00`, then also `FE D9 EF 01` would be acceptable. In the example I have set `2` as the acceptable range, meaning it will allow a value that is 2 less or more of the control value.

```
def create_list(value):
    # Convert a byte sequence (as string) into a list of int values.
    return [int(value[i:i + 2], 16) for i in range(0, len(value), 2)]


def check_if_close(value, control_value, accepted_range):
    print('Checking {} vs {}'.format(value, control_value))
    value = create_list(value)
    control_value = create_list(control_value)
    count = 0
    exact_match = 0
    for x in range(len(value)):
        if value[x] == control_value[x]:
            exact_match += 1
            continue
        for y in range(control_value[x] - accepted_range,
                       control_value[x] + accepted_range + 1):
            if y == value[x]:
                count += 1
                print('Unknown: {}, Predefined: {}'.format(y, control_value[x]))

    print('Exact matches:', exact_match)
    print('Bytes within range:', count)
    if exact_match + count == len(value):
        print('-- Within acceptable range\n')
    else:
        print('-- Not within acceptable range\n')

predefined = 'FFD8EE00'
unknown = 'FFD9EE00'
unknown2 = 'FED9EF01'
unknown3 = 'FFEFEE00'
check_if_close(unknown, predefined, 2)
check_if_close(unknown2, predefined, 2)
check_if_close(unknown3, predefined, 2)
```

`predefined` would be the value that you get from the `output_dict`, `unknown` variables simulates the hex values you get from the files as strings.

You can of course define yourself what is acceptable range, and what type of matches is acceptable. This code accepts a variation in each value pair, but you could easily define that you need to have at least 3 of 4 to be exact matches. In the example `unknown` and `unknown2` pass within acceptable range, while `unknown3` is not within acceptable range.

Hope this gives you some ideas for your program.

Comment: This looks very promising, I will have a look at it and see if it helps. Thanks a bunch.